# Text won't appear in IE8 and below

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer-8

The below function works fine in IE 9 and above but the text won't appear in IE 8 and below.

html :

```
<body onLoad="BuildBrwsrInfoMsg();" style="background:   url('../images/BeachBackground.jpg'); margin-top:0; " id="LoadingDisplay"  >
```

script :

```
function BuildBrwsrInfoMsg()
                {
    var maindiv = document.getElementById('Background-Header');
    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.setAttribute('id', 'browserInfo');  
    var spanBrwsrNameVersion = document.createElement('span');
    spanBrwsrNameVersion.textContent = "Browser Not Supported - You are using ("+ bowser.name + ' ' + bowser.version + ")";
    spanBrwsrNameVersion.setAttribute('class', 'BrowersTitle' );
    div.appendChild(spanBrwsrNameVersion);
    var spanBrwsrMsg = document.createElement('span');
    spanBrwsrMsg.textContent = "This browser may not be compatible with our website. For best results, it is suggested that you upgrade to the latest version. To download the latest version Click";
    spanBrwsrMsg.setAttribute('class', 'BrowersDescription' );
    div.appendChild(spanBrwsrMsg);

    var hideBtn = document.createElement('input');
    hideBtn.setAttribute('id', 'btnHideMsg');
    hideBtn.setAttribute('type', 'submit');
    hideBtn.setAttribute('value', 'Hide Message');
    div.appendChild(hideBtn);

        maindiv.insertBefore(div, maindiv.firstChild);                                          
  }
```

Answer (score 2):

It's all about the `textContent` property not being supported by IE < 9. That's confirmed on the [official documentations about the textContent property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent).

Comment: I like how Mozilla is now the official documentation, even for IE support ;) Anyway, as the linked page hints, for what the OP is trying to achieve, `innerText` can be used instead of `textContent` on IE8-. The code would also be a lot simpler and much shorter using jQuery (if you can).